# Remove tables from html files in python

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am looking to remove all tables from from html files, i.e. I want a copy of the  html files without include any tables in them [not to extract the tables from the files, or reformat it etc].

I was considering using regex, of the form:

```
 html_without_tables = re.sub(r"(?s)(?i)\<table .*\<\/table\>, " ", table)
```

However, there are countless posts saying don't parse html with regex, which makes me somewhat reluctant (although not really sure what problems would induce). I am guessing Beautifulsoup must be able to do it, but not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup, this is basically as easy as finding all `table` tags and calling [`.extract()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) on each:

```
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    table.extract()
```

Comment: Since OP doesn't need to extract the tables, `table.decompose()` also works

Comment: Can also one-liner it if you want `[table.decompose() for table in soup.find_all("table")]`

Comment: @cricket_007 one liner is actually not a good advice - we should avoid having side effects in list comprehensions and constructing an extra unneded list. Thanks.